# Spring 3 Async invoke service

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I want to build service, which will be invoked async, when i opening http page.

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping("/adv/{advName}")
public String showAdvertisement(Model model, @PathVariable("advName") String advName){


    Advertisement advertisement = advertisementService.getByUrl(advName);
    List<Advertisementimage> advertisementimages = advertisementImageService.getById(advertisement.getId());

**THIS SHOULD BE ASYNC : **
    getPhoneNumber.getPhoneNumberController(advertisement.getId());

    ..........


    return "frontend/advertisement";

}
```

AND Service is:

```
    @Service
public class GetPhoneNumber {

    @Autowired
    AdvertisementService advertisementService;

    @Autowired
    CustomerNotRegisteredService customerNotRegisteredService;

    @Autowired
    SystemCronService systemCronService;


    @Async
    public void getPhoneNumberController(int id){


        Advertisement advertisement = advertisementService.getById(id);


        String phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberSelenium(advertisement.getImportedUrl());
        customerNotRegisteredService.updatePhonuNumber(advertisement.getCustomerNotRegistered(), phoneNumber);


    }




}
```

But id doesn't work async - it is still sync. When i opening page, i'm waiting to finish "getPhoneNumber", then the page is loaded.

Should i add something else, to make it Async ?

Tanks

Comment: Call it using async ajax call.

Comment: I don't want to use Ajax, w want to do it on server side

Comment: So you want to divide one http request in two responses, i believe that cannot be done

Comment: OK, i get it, i need to add 
@EnableAsync before declaration :
public class GetPhoneNumber